# PHP: How to check if a var has been initiliazed? isset returns false when the var has been set to NULL

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $var = NULL;

    var_dump(isset($var)); // bool(false)
    var_dump(isset($unset_var)); // bool(false)
?>
```

isset($var) should return TRUE, since it has been set to NULL.

Is there any way to check for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use get_defined_vars() to get an array of the variables defined in the current scope and then test against it with array_key_exists();

Edited:

if you wanted a function to test existence you would create one like so:

```
function varDefined($name,$scope) {
  return array_key_exists($name, $scope);
}
```

and use like so in any given scope:

```
$exists = varDefined('foo',get_defined_vars());
```

Should work for any scope.

Comment: That's what I figured is the only way, since this is what happens in PHP: var_dump($random_nonexistent_var); // NULL

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not very pretty, but...

```
array_key_exists('var', $GLOBALS);
```

(You can't use `@is_null($var)`, because it evaluates to true either way [and it's not really good practice to suppress errors using the @ operator...])

Comment: Not really.  is_null() returns true for undefined variables.

Comment: Yeah, noticed that after I posted. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

if it's in global scope, you can try checking if the key exists in the $GLOBALS superglobal (using array_key_exists()).

but you're probably doing something wrong if you need to know this :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a global, you can do:

```
if(array_key_exists('var', $GLOBALS))
```

Answer (score -1):

Any unset var will evaluate to null:

```
php > $a = null;
php > var_dump($a === null);
bool(true)
php > var_dump($a === $b);
bool(true)
```

(using interactive console - php -a )

Answer (score -1):

Aren't variables initialized to NULL by default?  So, there isn't really a difference between one that hasn't been inited and one that you've set to NULL.

Comment: The difference is an entry in whatever namespace it exists in.

Comment: Yes, but what effect does that have on someone writing a script?  Do you have to handle the 2 cases differently?

Comment: Its an entry with no value (NULL is a value that means NO VALUE) - something IS null, it is not SET to null.  Entries in a namespace bare no meaning on detection of the initialization of a variable that has no value associated with it.

Comment: Again I ask, "Do you have to handle the 2 cases differently?" I want to be clear if we are talking about functionality as experienced by the script writer or something else.

Comment: You would have to handle them separately. is_null for null value checking and isset to see if the variable has been initiated.